# Getting Memory Out For using color picker

Tags: android, color-picker

I am getting Memory out error in Bitmap for one of my Play Store Apps. In this app I used color Picker for choosing color by User. And that gives me the error.
My used color Picker is:
https://github.com/chiralcode/Android-Color-Picker

Its normally take 6 to 7 MB memory.
Now I can't solve this problem. Is there any better Color Picker?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ambilwarna: https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna

Comment: Thanks. I am trying this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a great new android color picker that use material design I have forked an great project from github and made a simple-to-use android color picker dialog.

This is the project: [Android Color Picker](https://github.com/Pes8/android-material-color-picker-dialog)

[image]

### HOW TO USE IT

#### Adding the library to your project

The aar artifact is available at the **jcenter** repository. Declare the repository and the
dependency in your `build.gradle`.

(root)

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

(module)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.pes.materialcolorpicker:library:1.0.1'
}
```

#### Use the library

Create a color picker dialog object

```
final ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker(MainActivity.this, defaultColorR, defaultColorG, defaultColorB);
```

defaultColorR, defaultColorG, defaultColorB are 3 integer ( value 0-255) for the initialization of the color picker with your custom color value. If you don't want to start with a color set them to 0 or use only the first argument

Then show the dialog (when & where you want) and save the selected color

```
/* Show color picker dialog */
cp.show();

/* On Click listener for the dialog, when the user select the color */
Button okColor = (Button)cp.findViewById(R.id.okColorButton);

okColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        /* You can get single channel (value 0-255) */
        selectedColorR = cp.getRed();
        selectedColorG = cp.getGreen();
        selectedColorB = cp.getBlue();

        /* Or the android RGB Color (see the android Color class reference) */
        selectedColorRGB = cp.getColor();

        cp.dismiss();
    }
});
```

That's all :)